# Blocking access to a url by IP address

Tags: azure, iis, url-rewriting, web-config, umbraco

I am trying to block all access to the admin url for Umbraco (v7.2.8) for security reasons. I have the below in my web.config file, but it does not work. It is blocking all access to that url, even from the specified IP. I am running this locally on my machine from Visual Studio, so I am not sure what IP the site thinks I am coming in on, but I have tried all of them.  Does this web.config look ok?

```
  <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Restrict URL" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true" >
      <match url="^umbraco($|/)"/>
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">

        <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="^192\.168\.8\.100$" negate="true" />

       </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="/no-access/" /> 
    </rule>
  </rules>
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated! I will be deploying this to Azure eventually but wanted to get this working first. Perhaps it's because i'm running it locally?

EDIT:  I have tried the ipSecurity solution but receive the below error. I have installed the IP Security component for IIS. I am running the site from Visual Studio so I am not sure I can test it from here on the express service that VS uses? I have also changed to 'allow' in the following file;

%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config

[image]

Comment: How will you deploy this? Web App or Cloud Services?

Comment: I'll deploy it as a web app.

Comment: This just shows where the error is, not what the error is.  You also need to include the applicable sections of the web.config in your edit.  IIS express will work if ipSecurity is enable on your local machine - see the link referenced in my answer. Finally, I wouldn't make any manual changes to applicationHost.config to try and get this to work as you won't be able to replicate the solution on Azure WebApps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easier to accomplish with system.webServer >> security >> ipSecurity settings in the web.config inside a location element:

```
<location path="umbraco">
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false" denyAction="NotFound">
        <add allowed="true" ipAddress="192.168.8.100" />
      </ipSecurity>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

See [IIS IP Security](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity) more more details.  IP Security is enabled by defualt on Azure WebApps.

Comment: Hi - I have tried this solution but get the error above (edited in my post).  I will try to deploy to azure and see if this works, as you say azure has this enabled by default.  Will let you know and update answer.